# After user input a letter i need to print the previous letter, the letter entered, and the next letter

Tags: python, python-3.x

As the title says I need to print in alphabetical sequence the letter before the entered letter, the entered letter, and the letter after the entered letter.

For attempt #1 I get the result of the input letter being only B through Y and printing that letter.

For attempt #2 i get the letters of the alphabet B through Y in order but not specific letters out of that. (I found that one on another post so I'm confused on how it works.)

For attempt #3 I tried an Array, but i'm not sure how i can utilize an input with that.

## Attempt 1

```
valid_letters = 'bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyBCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY'

while True:
    letter = input("Enter a letter between B-Y ")
    if all(char in valid_letters for char in letter):
        break

print(letter)
```

## Attempt 2

```
letter = input("Enter a letter between B-Y ")

for c in range(1, 25):
    print(chr(ord('A')+c), end='')
```

## Attempt 3

```
valid_letters = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y']

print(valid_letters[5])
```

Comment: This seems like a homework question. Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) under "Asking about homework"

Answer (score 0):

```
# include A and Z in the string so we can print them if the user enters B or Y
letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

# keep going until the user quits by entering "q"
while True:
    letter = input("Enter a letter between B-Y, or q to quit ")

    if letter == 'q':
        print('Goodbye')
        break

    # if letter not in correct range, print a message and keep looping
    if not 'B' <= letter <= 'Y':
        print('Invalid input')
        continue

    # find the index position within letters of the entered letter
    position = letters.index(letter)

    # print previous, current, and next letters
    print ('letter before: %s' % letters[position-1])
    print ('entered letter: %s' % letter)
    print ('letter after: %s' % letters[position+1])
```

Comment: Thanks! is there a way to have the loop back to the input prompt again instead of ending when a wrong input was entered?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way using a for loop,

```
valid_letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']



letter = input("Enter letter betwen B and Y: ")

for i in range(len(valid_letters)):
    if letter == valid_letters[i]:
        print(valid_letters[i-1])
        print(valid_letters[i])
        print(valid_letters[i+1])
```